# Alert message in Forms

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I still can't get the right flow for this. I know it's simple and i think that my code is right but still the alert message is showing when i hit the buy button even if the input box is null. What i wanted is that no alert message will show if the input box is null but if the input box is filled then that;s the only time where the alert message will show when button is clicked. Here is my code:

```
 <?php
require_once('auth.php');
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <title>Athan Motorcycle</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 <!--
 .style1 {
color: #000000;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 24px;
  }
  -->
  </style>
  <!--<script type="text/javascript">
  function validateForm()
  {
  var a=document.forms["abc"]["qty"].value;
  if ((a==null || a==""))
  {
  alert("Please specify the quantity.");
   return false;
  }
  }
  </script>-->

  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="saveorder.php" name="abc" method="post">
  <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']; ?>" />
  <input name="transcode" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];   ?>" />
  <table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <?php
              if (isset($_GET['id']))
        {


        include('config.php');

        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM athan_products WHERE     product_id = $id and status='available'");
        $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td width="80"><img alt="Motor" src="images/motor/'.$row3['product_photo'].'"      /></td>';
  echo '<td width="200"><span class="style1">'.'</span></td>';
echo '<td width="120"></span></td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td width="80"><input name="name" type="text" value="'.$row3['partsname'].'"      readonly/><input name="ingre" type="hidden" value="'.$row3['product_ingredients'].'"/>      <input name="ids" type="hidden" value="'.$row3['id'].'"/></td>';
    echo '<td width="120"></span></td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  }
        ?>
  </table>
  <br />
  <label style="color:#000000;">Qty:
  <input type="number" min="1" id="qty" name="qty" required = "required" />


  </label>
  <br />
  <table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="color:#000000;"> 
  <tr>

   <!--<td width="179">Size</td>-->
  <td width="128">Price</td>
<td width="179">Description</td>
   <td width="93">Selection</td>
   </tr>
   <?php
              if (isset($_GET['id']))
        {


        include('config.php');

        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM athan_products WHERE     product_id = $id");
        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        $resultq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE product_id     LIKE '%".$id."%'");
        //$resultq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE product_id LIKE =$id");
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultq))
  { 
  $qwerty=$rows['qtyleft'];
  }     
  if ($qwerty !=0){         
  echo '<tr>';
   //echo '<td>'.$row3['product_size_name'].'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.$row3['price'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row3['description'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.'<input name="but" type="image" value="'.$row3['id'].'"      src="images/button.png"  onclick="return myFunction()" />'.'</td>';



   echo '</tr>';
   }
   else
   {
    echo '"This Item is not Available"';
    //echo '<td>'.'<h1>'.'"not available"'.'</h1>'.'</td>';
    }

        }

        }
        ?>


  </table>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction()
        {
        var a=document.forms["abc"]["qty"].value;
         if (a!=null || a!= ""){
        alert("Item has been successfully added to your Cart");
        }
        }
        </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Please don't pass variables into SQL like that... if the id was set to "index.php?id=true" you would get everything, and it gets worse... if someone set it to "1 UNION SELECT fields FROM table", they can get data from other tables (i.e. listing the usernames and email addresses from your users table)... this is known as SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OR should be an AND:

`if(a!=null && a!= "")`

Since `a` is not equal to `null`, the condition is true

Comment: oh Mr. @Rob M. you save my life. You have my respect sir:)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking for null or empty, you should check if a.length is 0

```
if(a.length !== 0){
 // do stuff
}
```

Comment: then maybe this is more useful to check for input type="number" hmm. now i think this is more appropriate because null and "" is for text right? :D